# Unity: How to fix square aspect ratio issue on Steam Deck

Tags: unity-game-engine, steam

I've developed a [game](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2604310/Panda__Crow_A_Paraglide_Adventure/) in Unity. It runs fine on Mac & Windows.

It runs fine on my friend's Steam Deck.
On my Steam Deck, it runs in a square 1:1 aspect ratio.
(Other games on my Steam Deck run fine as well.)

[image: Photo of Steam Deck running game]

I've tried to set the resolution in the Steam settings from default to native or 1280×800, but it still shows the whole game as 1:1 (correctly scaled, as my game is responsive) with the left and right sides of the screen black.

Is there something on a code level or a build level that I can do to fix this?

Unity Player settings for Windows / Mac builds are set to Fullscreen and native resolution.

[image: Screenshot of Unity player stteings]

Comment: Changing to Exclusive Fullscreen fixed it for me.